# {% now 'U' %} implementation in Jinja2?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to refresh the cache for static files especially during development stage. I had this caching issue in Django but it is quickly solved by adding {% now 'U' %} for query input

`src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}?{% now 'U' %}"`

Is there any similar implementation using Jinja2 in Flask? The other cache-refresh method in Flask is not as simple as this. I have been suggested with `src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.js', v='12052017') }}"` but it does not work really well ie. the js doesn't refresh.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have your browser not cache during development, instead?

Comment: Thanks Im gonna try this method as well. But my web application takes input data from user and output the data. The data is ported to a javascript file. That means that javascript file will constantly change as far as I know. Means I still need the js file to keep expiring in user's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom global variables for jinja2 :

```
import time 

def getTS():
    return time.time()

app.jinja_env.globals.update(getTS=getTS)
```

and in your template call it with {{ getTS() }}

example :

```
src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}?t={{ getTS() }}"
```

Comment: Let me try this. So I am putting this snippet in my *views.py* that render the template?

Comment: yes, after having defined `app` or whatever the variable name you use for flask

Comment: Works smoothly! Thanks.